# process.send() from a child_process launched by exec()

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm launching a Nightmare JS process from another Node process.  Normally, I'd launch Nightmare using `child_process.fork('./nightmare_script.js')`, and that allows the child process to send messages to the parent via `process.send()`.

However, when running it on an AWS Linux machine, it runs headless, so the script is launched as an argument to framebuffer, and I have to spawn the child process using `exec('xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" node nightmare_script.js')`.  However, the `process.send()` calls from the child don't (can't?) make it back to the parent.  Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: same problem here, did you figure it out?

Comment: After I read the documentation a little more carefully, I realized that `process.send()` is simply not available when using `exec()` - it's only available for `fork()`ed child processes.  However, i found that simply issuing a `console.log()` command from the `exec()`ed child process effectively sends a message to the parent.